# How to Separate Two jQuery Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I want to separate these functions. They should both work separately on click events:

**FIRST FUNCTION**

```
 $("ul.nav li").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash) {
           ACTION A
      });
$(window).trigger('hashchange');
 });
```

**SECOND FUNCTION**

```
 $("ul.subnav li").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash) {
           ACTION B
      });
$(window).trigger('hashchange');
 });
```

This is what happend in ACTION A:

```
 $mainContent
                .find(".maincontent")
                .fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " .maincontent", function() {
                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                            $pageWrap.animate({
                                height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                            });
                        });
                        $(".nav a").removeClass("active");
                        $(".nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("active");
                    });
                });
```

The Problem is that if I click the Link of the Second function always the the first function fires.

**Details of what I'm trying to do:**

First, I build my site on .php to serve poeple without JavaScript. Now I want to load the "maincontent" dynamically. So I found this script I'm using:

http://css-tricks.com/6336-dynamic-page-replacing-content/

It does do a great job if you **only** want to load "maincontents".

But my site has sub-navigation on some pages where I want to load the sub-content. In .php these sites use includes. So I get my content by: *href="page2.php?page=sub1"*

So, when I click on the sub-links now they load also dynamically but the script also on the whole maincontent loading area. So it doesn't really load content by .load() but the sub-content of the includes do appear.

So what I thought was just to separate this function. The first to simply load the maincontents and a second one for the sub-navigation to refresh only the sub-content area. I don't even understand how this script loads the include content dynamically since the link is the straight page2.php?page=sub1 link. All dynamic loaded content usually looks like "#index", without the ending ".php".

Some quick history:

I'm trying to get the best page structure. Deliver .php for non JavaScript user and then put some dynamic loading stuff over it. Always with the goal to keep the browser navigation and the browser links (for sharing) for each page in tact.

I'm not an jQuery expert. All I have learned so far was by trial and error and some logical thinking. But of course, I have a lack of fundamental knowledge in JavaScript.

So my "logical" question:

How can I tell the "nav" links to perform only their "$(window).bind"-Event and to tell the "subnav" links only to perfom their "$(window).bin"-event.

Is this the right thinking?

Since I've already been trying to solve it for nearly the last 18h, I'll appreciate any kind of help.

Thank you.

**IMPORTANT:**

With the first function I not just only load the maincontent but also I'm changing a div on the page with every link. So for any solution that might want to put it together in one, it won't work, cause they should do different things on different areas on the page. That's why I really need to call on the window.bind with each nav/subnav click.

Can anyone show me how?

Comment: When you make your site accessible without JavaScript, then `href="page2.php?page=sub1"` should return a complete HTML page anyway, right? Meaning, the "main content" (or however you call it) is included in the  response too, only the "sub content" is different. From this perspective, I think you don't even have to distinguish between main or sub content. Just included the content you get as response.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. But the reason why it wont't work I described in my question additionally now. Please could you show me somehow to make these two functions seperate? I'd apprechiate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's by the way the solution I came to:

After understanding that the haschange-event doesn't have to do anything with it (as long as you don't want to make the subcontent bookmarkable too) I just added a new load function for the subcontent:

```
$(function(){

            $("ul.linkbox li a").live('click', function (e) {
            newLink = $(this).attr("href");
            e.preventDefault();

                $(".textbox").find(".subcontent").fadeTo(200,0, function() {

                    $(".textbox").load(newLink +  " .subcontent" , function() {

                        $(".subcontent").fadeTo(200,1, function() {



                        }); 
                    }); 

                $("#wrapper").css("height","auto");
                $("ul.linkbox li a").removeClass("activesub");
                $("ul.linkbox li a[href='"+newLink+"']").addClass("activesub");

                });

        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Melros,
In your second function, you are binding to the event `hashchange2`, which is incorrect.  Instead, you **STILL** want to bind to `hashchange`.  Instead of:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange2', function() {
...
});
```

**Try:**

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
...
});
```

If you want to namespace your event subscriptions, you can suffix the ending of the event you are binding to with a period (`.`) and then the namespace:

```
$("#test").bind("click.namespace1", function() { });
$("#test").bind("click.namespace2", function() { });
```

Comment: Then it all flickers and the browser crashes.

Comment: Right, so you probably have some sort of infinite loop/circular reference going on.  Try commenting parts of each function out

Comment: What do you mean by that? Should I descript what I'm doing there? Sounds strange but I'm working with jquery by trial and error method I do not really know what I'm doing.

Comment: Ok, now I got so far, that I understand this: I have two different click events. Both need to be connected with their own $(window).bind('hashchange', function(). But how to do? Pleaese help. I'm trying already the whole day.

Comment: ok, how do I give the function the name? function namespace1() {} ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that you want to execute action A when a link inside `.nav` is clicked, and action B when a link inside `.subnav` is clicked.

You can just put these actions inside the event handlers. Furthermor, if `.subnav` is nested inside `.nav`, you have to restrict your selector:

```
// consider only direct children
$("ul.nav > li").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    if(window.location.hash !== href) {
        Action A

        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    }

    return false;
});

// consider only direct children
$("ul.subnav > li").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    if(window.location.hash !== href) {
        Action B

        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    }

    return false;
});
```

I don't think listening to the `hashchange` event will help you here, as this event is triggered in both cases and you cannot know which element was responsible (you probably can somehow, but why make it overly complicated?).

Comment: at first, thank you alot for responding. But for the reason that I load content dynamically I need the hash to navigation in the browser. I updated my Question that you see which content I'm loading. But would it be possible to work with hashchange even if it's complicated? I'm so frustrated right now. Need to get it to work somehow.

Comment: Ok, it is probably easy to run the corresponding action when you clicked a link and the hash changes. But if you want to make the site work with the navigation buttons, you'd also need a way to find out the appropriate action solely based on the the value of the hash. You have to think about this first. How can you find out which action to perform only given the value of the hash? Or maybe you don't even need two different actions? What are they actually doing? The better you describe your ultimate goal, the easier it is for us to help you.